# Send HTTP Request to device through Mac Address?

Tags: ip, mac-address

Is it possible to communicate with a device solely through a device's MAC address? Alternatively, can you get a device's IP address through its MAC address? The point is to communicate with a remote device that has a non-static IP. I would like to avoid the use of static IP's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MAC address is only relevant on the local layer-2 LAN, so even if you could use an upper-layer protocol with only the MAC address, it wouldn't do you any good since the layer-2 frame from your host will have the gateway MAC address as the destination MAC address, and your MAC address as the source MAC address. The frame will be stripped off at the gateway, losing even your source MAC address.

MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, and they are only used on the local LAN. To get to a different network, you need the layer-3 network (IP) address. For applications to communicate with each other, they need to know the transport protocol (TCP, UDP, etc.) and the layer-4 address (port).

Comment: Would if I am only communicating on the local network?

Comment: That depends on what you are doing. There are protocols which only use layer-2, but it is usually done through a network stack, and each layer in the stack will pass off to the layer above it. If you don't have IP as the layer-3, then how does layer-2 know where to pass its payload unless you have a different layer-3 protocol, which would also require a layer-3 address for itself.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer, and TCP uses IP for the network layer, etc. You need each layer to have an address for that layer.

Comment: It would seem to me then, I do not have much of a choice. My concern is the communication with a remote device whose IP is subject to change on the Local Network. I see really only two options then: request a static IP from the router (if possible), or notify the communications server if the node's IP changes. Would this be accurate? For curious readers, I found this to be an excellent resource for an explanation of network layers: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131014684/samplechapter/0131014684_ch02.pdf.

Comment: You can look into dynamic DNS as a possible option.

Answer (score 0):

If your device has IPv6 support, you can make a connection to the link-local address, which has a deterministic relationship with the MAC address.

Comment: In most cases, with modern OSes like Windows or Linux, this is not true. By default, Windows and most Linux distributions use random addressing, not the original SLAAC which used the MAC address as a modified EUI-64 as the Interface ID.